# Compiling a package in CMD

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, compiler-construction

I have made a program that runs in eclipse, but I have some problems trying to compile and run it from the command line.  The deal is its in a package, and also importing some things:

```
package game;

import game.Elements.Element;
import game.Elements.InvalidElementException;
```

etc, so i cant just use -javac "file.java"  since it cant find the imports/package. 
I'm sure its out there, but I'm too tired and can't get it running.
if i have the filed in a folder  /src/game  and main class is Coolgame.java  what command could i use?  Thanks.

Comment: Try nameing all *.java files after javac. (This assumes everything you import (except the JDK stuff) is below the folder game.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command to compile everything, including the classes in subpackages.

```
javac game/*.java game/Elements/*.java  # and similar
```

Of course, you may import stuff from somewhere else, a jar/library? Then adding a classpath option is required.

Answer (score 0):

Explore the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile).

One solution could be to create a file containing all classes to compile, named `classes`:

```
MyClass1.java
MyClass2.java
MyClass3.java
```

and a file called `options` to specify more compiler arguments:

```
-d classes
```

Your compiled classes will now be moved into a directory called `classes`. If you use external JARs, extend the classpath with the option `-cp` in this file.

Try it out with `javac @options @classes`.